# Multiple UDP messages sent to single reveiver

Tags: c++, networking, udp

Here is the situation:
I have multiple clients and one host. The message format&size is specified.
suppose all the clients send a message at the same time, that is N message are send to host.

My question is: will the host receive a mixed message, I mean will host receives some bits of message A and followed by some bits from message B ? Or the messages will be received in whole?

Thanks

Comment: All trying to send on the same port?

Comment: Yes, all clients are sending to same port on host. in my program, I only have one udp socket in server part.

Comment: Well then I dont believe you can have a situation where they are sending at the same time. I believe that once one client has opened a connection to the port, no other client will be able to do so until it is closed.

Comment: TCP has the restriction that, once opened, a peer-to-peer socket can contain data from only the two parties that are named in the 5-tuple (ip1, port1, TCP, port2, ip2). UDP sockets can be created that accept datagrams sent to it (i.e., to the specified destination port and ip address) from any source (i.e., source port and source IP address).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read data from the socket (e.g., with `recvfrom`) all the data returned from that call will be from a single source.

Comment: Datagrams sent by different applications will not be mixed at the receiving application (assuming the underlying stack behaves correctly, as stacks in the common operating system will).

Comment: @ArtSwri: You are correct from a practical standpoint. It is certainly an unlikely situation for reassembly not to occur correctly.  However, I am pretty sure that I have observed cases of fragmentation that did not result in reassembly.  I've had to deal with UDP issues in a lot of sketchy network situations over the years.

Comment: " I believe that once one client has opened a connection to the port, no other client will be able to do so until it is closed. " If two clients send msg to host, host could handle one msg at a time, will host just dump another msg or it will be buffered?

Comment: This answer is not correct. If the datagram gets fragmented and a fragment gets lost, the entire datagram is lost, as there is no retransmission mechanism. This means that UDP datagrams are received entire or not at all. There is zero possibility of the data being 'mixed'.

Comment: @Mark Wilkins I have a fair amount of experience digging around in stack code. For a PC or bigger device, the stacks are complete and mature and will either deliver the whole datagram or will drop it (e.g., if reassembly fails for lack of segment(s)). For small devices, I have seen a considerable variety in the quality of the stack implementation down to extremely poor/limited reassembly (or none at all). Have not seen any (yet) that deliver parts/pieces of a  datagram.

Comment: @user1247142 The message will be buffered in the socket receive buffer if it fits, otherwise it will be dropped.

Comment: @MarkWilkins You can receive a partial packet with UDP if your application receive buffer is too small. That's not the same thing as 'mixed data', which you simply cannot receive via UDP. Otherwise (a) the TCP stack would be non-RFC-compliant and therefore not ship, and (b) *nothing* would work, from DNS onwards. Your statement 'If they are not reassembled into a single packet, they could be "mixed"' is completely meaningless.

Comment: @EJP:  Right - I know that.  That's not what I was referring to.  On that Win98 machine I mentioned, I was dealing with packets that had been fragmented and not reassembled.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't believe it. Sorry. Your recollections are so vague and ancient that they don't constitute adequate evidence.

Comment: @EJP: That is a reasonable response.  And you are right; ten years in this business is ancient.  I removed all of the text in question.

Answer (score 5):

UDP datagrams are always received by the 'end client' as a whole datagram. That is, if the sender sends a datagram of 10,000 bytes, it will be received as 10,000 bytes (and not some combination of smaller datagrams that add up to 10,000 bytes). The path taken by the datagram (namely IP) may cause the datagram to be fragmented during transmission, but the receiving UDP/IP stack will reassemble the datagram before delivery to an application program.

Comment: No, applications that require ordered delivery must restore datagram ordering themselves.

Comment: Yes, whole datagrams may get delivered to the endpoint 'out of order'. My answer is talking about the fragments of a _single_ datagram, not multiple datagrams.